# Как выполнить скрипт на форме в visual studio?

Tags: winforms, c++, visual-studio

Текущая задача состоит в выполнении скрипта на форме, использую компонент webBrowser, 
с  html кодом из msdn все работает:
[ссылка на msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documenttext.aspx) (тут с# но из примера я взял только код, пишу на си++)
Однако уже мой скрипт по непонятной причине студия пытается обработать как сишный код, ругается на синтаксис и различные идентификаторы, попробовал перед тем как установить свойство DocumentText загнать весь скрипт в вектор, не вышло, так же ругается на синтаксис.
Благодарю за ответы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если все было сделано как по указанной ссылке, то код страницы со скриптом - это обычная строка и какое дело VisualStudiо до того, что там в строковой переменной. Другое дело, если в тексте этой "строки" будут одинарные кавычки (а они то там скорее всего будут - скрипт как ни как).
Поэтому, план такой. Вначале в текстовом редакторе пишем html код с скриптом (а не просто сам скрипт). Загружаем в обычный браузер, проверяем, что оно работает так, как ожидается.
Теперь, вставляем полученный код с файла в студию, при этом экранируя все нужные символы - как минимум одинарную кавычку (просто добавив перед ней слеш -  ) и сами слеши, добавив перед ними также слеш. При этом максимум на что должна ругаться студия - так это орфографичесие ошибки.